# Align logo with navigation links and place the logo above links in responsive mode

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to align a logo in par with a couple of navigation links in which most sites would have the logo on the left and a couple of links on the right (is what i'm trying to achieve).

And I have a media query that makes the header logo appear above the navigation links.

However it doesn't seem to work.

I do have an external JQuery that runs the responsive part of the site when the browser hits 600px in width.

I need some help in two areas:

1. Aligning the logo in par with the navigation links. Logo is labeled as JJ, with the second J inverted.
2. Placing the logo above the navigation links and centering it and the navigation links when the width of the browser hits 720px.

`Code sample:` http://jsfiddle.net/ERJp5/3/

thank you.

Comment: wouldn't this be easier for you if you used twitter-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

The floaty transitioning border on your "Special Box" was pushing the element down. I added "margin-top: -13px;" to it and it looks much better.

```
/*----Special box----*/
header nav ul li.menu-item-444 a {
/*background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34495e;
border-radius: 15px;*/
font-family: Orena, Sans-Serif;
font-size:25px;
float: left;
padding: 13px;
margin-top: -13px;
color:white;
/*transition: color 0.25s ease-in;*/
}
```

Check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/juhc4/

**EDIT:**

Here's a (slightly hacky) way you can move your logo based on screen width:

Set up **two** logos, one of class bigscreen and one of class smallscreen:

One div in front of your `ul` since you want it to float above everything, class `smallscreen`:

```
 <div id="menu-item-444" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-444 smallscreen">
    <a href="index.html" title="Home">J<span class="mirror">J</span></a></div>
```

And your `li` element, class `bigscreen`:

```
<li id="menu-item-444" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-444 bigscreen">
            <a href="index.html" title="Home">J<span class="mirror">J</span></a></li>
```

Next, we set up our `@media` queries in the CSS, turning one logo on and the other one off depending on how wide the screen is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
.bigscreen {
   display:none !important;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 721px){

.smallscreen {
   display:none !important;
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/ERJp5/1/

Comment: That worked! Didn't think of adding a margin. Now, I just need help to center the logo with the navigation once it has hit a 720px width. :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I tried out your solution but somehow it works partially. I added in a few elements previously before trying out this solution and it has somehow added onto the Responsive Menu too in which I need to remove. Would you mind taking a look at the updated JFiddle I just uploaded on the question? Thanks